# update query slider position based on value from textbox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

how can i update slider's position if slider's value differs from value from a textbox ?

```
$("#slider").slider({   
max: 30000,
min: 1000,
step: 1000,
range: true, 
animate: true,
values: [1000, 15000],
slide: function(even, ui)
{
$("#edit-field-price-value-min").val(ui.values[0]);
$("#edit-field-price-value-max").val(ui.values[1]);
}
});
```

as you can see i am changing with the slider the values on some textbox but i want it vice versa also

i'd like to be using a if statement so that at any moment if the values from text box would change the slider would as well

is it possible to do it onload maybe ?

```
<div id="slider"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to set an event during $(document).ready() to your two text fields. Depending on the behavior, you could use the change() event or blur() event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#edit-field-price-value-min').change(function(){
        $('#slider').slider( "values" , 0 , $(this).val() );
    });
    $('#edit-field-price-value-max').change(function(){
        $('#slider').slider( "values" , 1 , $(this).val() );
    });
});
```

So when your textfield is changed, it will update the slider.

Comment: how can i make it refresh-proof also ?

Comment: You have a few options. You can set and get cookies using the [jQuery Cookie Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie). You can also use ajax calls to set the values to your web app (i.e. PHP) and then set them when you generate the page.

Comment: i found a tutorial for the plugin you mentioned, but i wouldn't know how to link it to the slider, it seems it's a boolean value there only, and i need the actual value of the textfield.. i'm kinda noob in jquery